# Prolog won't return true(yes) when it should

Tags: prolog

```
mergelist([],[],[]).
mergelist([X],[],[X]).
mergelist([],[Y],[Y]).
```

I'm running this query `?-mergelist([1],[],[1]).`
which returns true

But then I run this query `?-mergelist([1,2],[],[1,2]).`it returns false(no).

I'm not sure what's wrong.

I'm using ECLiPSe 6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog can't pattern match [1,2] with any of:

- []
- [X]

[X] is specifically designed to pattern match with a one-element list.

Try this:

```
mergelist(L,[],L) :- is_list(L).
mergelist([],L,L) :- is_list(L).
```